# How to sort a list by length of string followed by reverse alphabetical order?

Tags: python, sorting

> Given a list of words, return a list with the same words in order of
> length (longest to shortest), the second sort criteria should be
> alphabetical. Hint: you need think of two functions.

This is what I have so far:

```
def bylength(word1,word2):
    return len(word2)-len(word1)

def sortlist(a):
    a.sort(cmp=bylength)
    return a
```

it sorts by length but I don't know how to apply the second criteria to this sort, which is by alphabetical descending.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

You can do it in two steps like this:

```
the_list.sort() # sorts normally by alphabetical order
the_list.sort(key=len, reverse=True) # sorts by descending length
```

Python's sort is stable, which means that sorting the list by length leaves the elements in alphabetical order when the length is equal.

You can also do it like this:

```
the_list.sort(key=lambda item: (-len(item), item))
```

Generally you never need `cmp`, it was even removed in Python3. `key` is much easier to use.

Comment: the lambda solution is awe-some!

Comment: The second solution was a bit of art and I didn't know key works that way!

Comment: @jochen When I do this I get an `'str' object has no attribute 'sort'` error because I'm not using a list. It's a string from opening the csv. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Edison old question, but you could split at commas/line separators to create a list and then apply this solution

Comment: just wondering why you are returning a tuple in the lambda function when you could only return `-len(item)`

Answer (score 7):

```
n = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd', 'dddl', 'yyyyy']

for i in reversed(sorted(n, key=len)):
    print i
```

> yyyyy dddl dddd ccc bbb aaa

```
for i in sorted(n, key=len, reverse=True):
     print i
```

> yyyyy dddd dddl aaa bbb ccc

Comment: This only works if the array is already sorted. Only `sorted( sorted( iterable ), key=len )` gives the correct answer always.

Comment: @user I just tried with unsorted array . Getting the same (correct) result . Can you please provide your input array ?

Comment: `sorted( ['bb', 'b', 'aa', 'a'], key=len, reverse=True)` produces `['bb', 'aa', 'b', 'a']`, but it should be `['aa', 'bb', 'a', 'b']` as get from `sorted( sorted( ['bb', 'b', 'aa', 'a'] ), key=len, reverse=True)`

Comment: This is simply sorting by string length in descending order.

Answer (score 3):

```
-Sort your list by alpha order, then by length.

See the following exmple:

>>> coursesList = ["chemistry","physics","mathematics","art"]
>>> sorted(coursesList,key=len)
['art', 'physics', 'chemistry', 'mathematics']
>>> coursesList.append("mopsosa")
>>> sorted(coursesList,key=len)
['art', 'physics', 'mopsosa', 'chemistry', 'mathematics']
>>> coursesList.sort()
>>> sorted(coursesList,key=len)
['art', 'mopsosa', 'physics', 'chemistry', 'mathematics']
```

Answer (score 2):

**First sort by Alphabet and then sort by Length.**

Here is a working example

```
mylist.sort()
mylist = sorted(mylist, key=len, reverse=False)

# Print the items on individual line
for i in mylist:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

Although Jochen Ritzel said you don't need cmp, this is actually a great use case for it! Using cmp you can sort by length and then alphabetically at the same time in half the time sorting twice would take!

```
def cmp_func(a, b):
    # sort by length and then alphabetically in lowercase
    if len(a) == len(b):
        return cmp(a, b)
    return cmp(len(a), len(b))

sorted_the_way_you_want = sorted(the_list, cmp=cmp_func)
```

Example:

```
>>> the_list = ['B', 'BB', 'AA', 'A', 'Z', 'C', 'D']
>>> sorted(the_list, cmp=cmp_func)
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'Z', 'AA', 'BB']
```

Note, if your list is a mix of upper and lower case replace `cmp(a, b)` with `cmp(a.lower(), b.lower())` [as python sorts 'a' > 'Z'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4806946/738924).

In python3 you'd need to be sorting objects with `__lt__` style comparison functions defined or `functools.cmp_to_key()` [which does that for you.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16362818/738924)

Comment: not very interesting as `cmp` doesn't exist in python 3 anymore (you said it yourself)

Answer (score -2):

```
def cmp_func(a, b):
    # sort by length and then alphabetically in lowercase
    if len(a) == len(b):
        return cmp(a, b)
    return cmp(len(a), len(b))

sorted_the_way_you_want = sorted(the_list, cmp=cmp_func)
```

Comment: You need to sourround your code with ``` or prepend 4 spaces to put it in code blocks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.