# Start a Function at Given Time

Tags: python, time, scheduler

How can I run a function in *Python*, at a given time?

For example:

```
run_it_at(func, '2012-07-17 15:50:00')
```

and it will run the function `func` at 2012-07-17 15:50:00.

I tried the [sched.scheduler](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html#scheduler-objects), but it didn't start my function.

```
import time as time_module
scheduler = sched.scheduler(time_module.time, time_module.sleep)
t = time_module.strptime('2012-07-17 15:50:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
t = time_module.mktime(t)
scheduler_e = scheduler.enterabs(t, 1, self.update, ())
```

What can I do?

Comment: What operating system? You'll likely need to run it with a program external to python, such as cron on unix.

Comment: Why not?  What delay did you set for `enter` (assuming that is what you tried)?

Comment: How did you try to use `sched.scheduler`?

Comment: i used `sched.scheduler` because i googled it :)

Comment: Did you call `scheduler.run()` ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Reading the docs from http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sched.html:

Going from that we need to work out a delay (in seconds)...

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
```

Then use `datetime.strptime` to parse '2012-07-17 15:50:00' (I'll leave the format string to you)

```
# I'm just creating a datetime in 3 hours... (you'd use output from above)
from datetime import timedelta
run_at = now + timedelta(hours=3)
delay = (run_at - now).total_seconds()
```

You can then use `delay` to pass into a  `threading.Timer` instance, eg:

```
threading.Timer(delay, self.update).start()
```

Comment: The datetime arithmetics on local time may fail if the utc offset of the local timezone has changed between `now` and `run_at` e.g., around DST transitions. Convert the local time to UTC or POSIX timestamp to perform  the calculations. See [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26313848/4279).

Comment: You can use `total_seconds` directly on `timedelta`: `datetime.timedelta(hours=3).total_seconds()`

Comment: how accurate is this method?  Im looking for less than 10ms error

Comment: @bakalolo: thread scheduling on Windows happens at 1/64 s ~ 16ms. It'll likely not be better than that.

Comment: how to reuse threading.Timer at multi call?

Answer (score 36):

Take a look at the Advanced Python Scheduler, APScheduler: http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/index.html

They have an example for just this usecase:
http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/dateschedule.html

```
from datetime import date
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

# Start the scheduler
sched = Scheduler()
sched.start()

# Define the function that is to be executed
def my_job(text):
    print text

# The job will be executed on November 6th, 2009
exec_date = date(2009, 11, 6)

# Store the job in a variable in case we want to cancel it
job = sched.add_date_job(my_job, exec_date, ['text'])
```

Answer (score 26):

Might be worth installing this library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule, basically helps do everything you just described. Here's an example:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)
schedule.every().monday.do(job)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("13:15").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I searched for a special solution and this will change a lot of my applications now. I didn't know it exists. Thanks a lot, Daniel!

Comment: note that `schedule` does not take into account the duration of `job`; if `job` takes 2 min, then `schedule.every().hour.do(job)` will actually run every 62 min.  IMO APScheduler is a far better package.

Comment: Daniel, OP asked for running function at specific time, could you explain how I can solve that problem with schedule? Like def run_at(f, datetime) -> run f when datetime.now() == datetime

Answer (score 15):

Here's an update to stephenbez' answer for version 3.5 of APScheduler using Python 2.7:

```
import os, time
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def tick(text):
    print(text + '! The time is: %s' % datetime.now())


scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
dd = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=3)
scheduler.add_job(tick, 'date',run_date=dd, args=['TICK'])

dd = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=6)
scheduler.add_job(tick, 'date',run_date=dd, kwargs={'text':'TOCK'})

scheduler.start()
print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))

try:
    # This is here to simulate application activity (which keeps the main thread alive).
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    # Not strictly necessary if daemonic mode is enabled but should be done if possible
    scheduler.shutdown()
```

Comment: @Doezer but then the answer would not contribute to his earned reputation

Answer (score 7):

I've confirmed the code in the opening post works, just lacking `scheduler.run()`. Tested and it runs the scheduled event. So that is another valid answer.

```
>>> import sched
>>> import time as time_module
>>> def myfunc(): print("Working")
...
>>> scheduler = sched.scheduler(time_module.time, time_module.sleep)
>>> t = time_module.strptime('2020-01-11 13:36:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> t = time_module.mktime(t)
>>> scheduler_e = scheduler.enterabs(t, 1, myfunc, ())
>>> scheduler.run()
Working
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue: I could not get absolute time events registered with `sched.enterabs` to be recognized by `sched.run`.  `sched.enter` worked for me if I calculated a `delay`, but is awkward to use since I want jobs to run at specific times of day in particular time zones.

In my case, I found that the issue was that the default `timefunc` in the `sched.scheduler` initializer is not `time.time` (as in the [example](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sched.html)), but rather is `time.monotonic`.  `time.monotonic` does not make any sense for "absolute" time schedules as, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.monotonic), "The reference point of the returned value is undefined, so that only the difference between the results of consecutive calls is valid."

The solution for me was to initialize the scheduler as

`scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)`

It is unclear whether your time_module.time is actually time.time or time.monotonic, but it works fine when I initialize it properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
dateSTR = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S" )
if dateSTR == ("20:32:10"):
   #do function
    print(dateSTR)
else:
    # do something useful till this time
    time.sleep(1)
    pass
```

Just looking for a Time of Day / Date event trigger:
as long as the date "string" is tied to an updated "time" string, it works as a simple TOD function. You can extend the string out to a date and time.

whether its lexicographical ordering or chronological order comparison,
as long as the string represents a point in time, the string will too.

someone kindly offered this link:

[String Comparison Technique Used by Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/string-comparison-technique-used-by-python)

Answer (score 0):

had a really hard time getting these answers to work how i needed it to,

but i got this working and its **accurate to .01 seconds**

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
    
sched = BackgroundScheduler()
sched.start()

def myjob():
    print('job 1 done at: ' + str(dt.now())[:-3])

dt = datetime.datetime
Future = dt.now() + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=2000)
job = sched.add_job(myjob, 'date', run_date=Future)
```

tested accuracy of timing with this code:
at first i did 2 second and 5 second delay, but wanted to test it with a more accurate measurement so i tried again with 2.55 second delay and 5.55 second delay

```
dt = datetime.datetime
Future = dt.now() + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=2550)
Future2 = dt.now() + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=5550)

def myjob1():
    print('job 1 done at: ' + str(dt.now())[:-3])
def myjob2():
    print('job 2 done at: ' + str(dt.now())[:-3])

print(' current time: ' + str(dt.now())[:-3])
print('  do job 1 at: ' + str(Future)[:-3] + ''' 
  do job 2 at: ''' + str(Future2)[:-3])
job = sched.add_job(myjob1, 'date', run_date=Future)
job2 = sched.add_job(myjob2, 'date', run_date=Future2)
```

and got these results:

```
 current time: 2020-12-10 19:50:44.632
  do job 1 at: 2020-12-10 19:50:47.182 
  do job 2 at: 2020-12-10 19:50:50.182
job 1 done at: 2020-12-10 19:50:47.184
job 2 done at: 2020-12-10 19:50:50.183
```

**accurate to .002 of a second with 1 test**

**but i did run a lot of tests and accuracy ranged from .002 to .011**

**never going under the 2.55 or 5.55 second delay**

Answer (score -2):

```
#everytime you print action_now it will check your current time and tell you should be done

import datetime  
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()  
current_time.hour  

schedule = {
    '8':'prep',
    '9':'Note review',
    '10':'code',
    '11':'15 min teabreak ',
    '12':'code',
    '13':'Lunch Break',
    '14':'Test',
    '15':'Talk',
    '16':'30 min for code ',
    '17':'Free',
    '18':'Help ',
    '19':'watever',
    '20':'watever',
    '21':'watever',
    '22':'watever'
}

action_now = schedule[str(current_time.hour)]
```

Comment: a bit of explanation would make this a better answer.

Comment: This is a look up table. The question is asking for a way to initiate a function at a specific time. You would need to add more code to make this feasible.