# How to zip a folder in Python?

Tags: python

well, I have a little knowledge in python and I try to zip a folder

```
import os
import zipfile

def zipdir(path, ziph):
# ziph is zipfile handle
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file))

if __name__ == '__main__':
zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('Python.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
zipdir('tmp/', zipf)
zipf.close()
```

so, I get this answer but I don't understand the code very well and I don't know how to implement it in my own code, I mean where should I type my folder name, for example,**Test_folder**, where to type it in the code to implement a zip process in it, Can you rewrite the code and type **test_folder** in the true place in code.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted result? Can you provide some code?

Comment: Mix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523918/python-start-a-function-at-given-time and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855095/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-of-a-directory

Comment: @Polymer can you help me in that?

Comment: I am not sure what the question is here. Other than some missing indents, the posted code is actually correct and will zip the directory and its sub-directories.

Comment: @LeoK let's say I have a directory named as  **test**, I want to zip it, in any place of code should I write **test** to zip the folder

Comment: Have you tried `zipdir('test', zipf)`? Also make sure you indent your python code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your folder name in this line.

```
zipdir('tmp/', zipf)
```