# Python schedule a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem. I would like to schedule a function at 09:00 for every fifteen minutes. and finish the execution at 11:00.

```
def function1():
     print("Hello")
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: as answered bellow, this is relatively hardly attainable by programming languages. Just configure Unix crontab for your script.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Unix machine, you can write a cronjob to run a Python file every 15 minutes (or on any schedule you like). The file should contain and call whatever functions you want.

Open your crontab with `crontab` or `crontab -e` in shell.

Then you can add, for example:

```
*/15 09-10 * * * python3 /path/to/my/file.py
```

Which will run every 15 minutes starting at 9:00 and the last run will occur at 10:45. If you want a run at 11:00 as the final run for the day, that will have to be another line in the crontab like:

```
0 11 * * * python3 /path/to/my/file.py
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention your operation system.

On Linux and MacOS, use [`cron`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

On Windows, use [`Scheduled Tasks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page).

Comment: windows and linux :P

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible approaches:

1)  You can use your operating system's scheduling system to have your script ran at the appropriate times.  On Windows, this is called the Task Scheduler.  On Linux, this is called cron.  See Henry Woody's reply for specifics on using cron.

2)  You can write code to calculate exactly how long you need to wait until your code runs.  Then, you run your code, and repeat.  See this post for a lot more detail: [Python - Start a Function at Given Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523918/python-start-a-function-at-given-time)

The first option will be the easiest and seems like the most appropriate given your description, but both approaches have appropriate use cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple cron job to schedule your job or Try orchestration framework like Airflow - http://airflow.incubator.apache.org/

> Airflow is a platform to programmatically author, schedule and monitor
>   workflows.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in pure Python with no external libraries or tools (like cron), you can do something like this, where you would calculate the time until your action, and sleep for that amount of time.

If you run this, the process will be running forever, sleeping until 9:00 every day, at which point it will run function1() and wait for the next quarter, until 11:00.

Beware that if function1() takes more than 15 minutes to run, this will skip that quarter execution and wait for the next one. Also if you start if after 9:00, it will wait for the next day before the first execution.

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

def wait_for_nine():
    now = datetime.now()
    if now.hour < 9:
        wait_for = datetime.replace( now, hour=9, minute=0, second=0)
    else:
        wait_for = datetime.replace( now + timedelta(days=1), hour=9, minute=0, second=0)
    delta = wait_for - datetime.now()
    time.sleep(delta.seconds)

def wait_fifteen():
    now = datetime.now()
    next_quarter = 15 * (int(now.minutes / 15) + 1)
    wait_for = datetime.replace(now, minute=next_quarter % 60, second=0) + timedelta(hours= int(next_quarter / 60))
    delta = wait_for - dt.datetime.now()
    time.sleep(delta.seconds)

while True:
    wait_for_nine()
    now = datetime.now()
    eleven = datetime.replace(now, hour=11,minute=0, second= 0 )
    while now <= eleven:
        function1()
        wait_fifteen()
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to what mentioned above (cron or pure Python) you could try schedule module:

```
from datetime import datetime

import schedule


def function1():
    print("Hello")


schedule.every(15).minutes.do(function1)

while True:
    if datetime.now().hour == 9:
        schedule.run_pending()
    if datetime.now().hour == 11:
        schedule.clear()
        break
```

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.