# How to make datetime constantly check the time and send a message in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, discord, discord.py

So I want my discord bot to send out a message in the server every morning at 7 am. Using my variable time which is:

```
time = datetime.datetime.now()
```

and doing time.hour and time.minute, I can make it print something at the time i want using:

```
if time.hour == 7:
    print('Its 7 am')
```

but using a whle statement datetime doesnt actually refresh the time. Second of all if there are any discord.py people how would i send the message without using an event refernec or command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
time = datetime.datetime.now

while True:
  if time().hour == 7 and time().minute == 0:
    print("Its 7 am")
  sleep(60)
```

The reason the time doesn't actually refresh in your code is that you are storing the result of a function in the variable, not the function itself. If you don't include the parenthesis then the function gets stored in the variable so it can be called later using `variable()`.

Comment: oh that makes sense, but what does the sleep(60) do? Is that like a refresh timer so every 60 seconds it refreshes?

Comment: Without the sleep(60) it would print every time it repeats until 7:01, the sleep(60) makes sure it only checks every minute.

Answer (score 0):

This question could already be answered on the following link:

[Python - Start a Function at Given Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523918/python-start-a-function-at-given-time)

Given the following information:

Reading the docs from http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sched.html:

Going from that we need to work out a delay (in seconds)...

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
```

Then use datetime.strptime to parse '2012-07-17 15:50:00' (I'll leave the format string to you)

```
# I'm just creating a datetime in 3 hours... (you'd use output from above)
from datetime import timedelta
run_at = now + timedelta(hours=3)
delay = (run_at - now).total_seconds()
```

You can then use delay to pass into a threading.Timer instance, eg:

```
threading.Timer(delay, self.update).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Install schedule with pip:

```
$ pip install schedule
```

You could do something like that:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("Its 7 am")

schedule.every().day.at("07:00").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```