# How to send mail on different time using python?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyzmail

#### Code I have

```py
def callback(message):
   if not message:
      Mailer().send_feed_error_report('Empty Message')
   if "message_type" not in message:
      Mailer().send_feed_error_report('"message_type" not in message')


class Mailer():
   def send_feed_error_report(self, error_info):
      send_mail(error_info)

callback(message)
```

`send_mail` will only send a mail. It is a simple function for sending mail.

### I want to

- send mail only after 1 hour
- other functions/code has to run in parallel, so I'd like to avoid using `time.sleep()`

Comment: What's wrong with `time.sleep`?

Comment: Also, what's the `send_mail` function?

Comment: because other functions are needed that time to run.

Comment: Use cron tab on Linux

Comment: What about spinning off a thread?

Comment: send_mail will send only mail. It is a simple function for sending mail.

Comment: spinning off thread might be useful.

Comment: can we use a variable that will store a last sent mail time?

Comment: @Shubham_Mahitkar, please [edit] your question to add clarification and update your question, not in comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Start a Function at Given Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523918/python-start-a-function-at-given-time)

Answer (score 2):

#### Scheduling in Python

You can use `threading.Timer` to **schedule a function** to run after a specified time (*delay*).

See Python's *Event scheduler* module [`sched`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html).

#### How it works

Passing the *delay* in seconds will start the thread after the given delay and execute it independent of the main thread. Hence does not block your main thread.

You can pass parameters to your function like a regular thread using `args` as third argument.

```py
delay_by = 1 * 60 * 60 # in seconds
threading.Timer(delay_by, send_mail).start()
```

Source:
[Start a Function at Given Time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11524152/5236575)