# What does string comparison do?

Tags: python

What does string comparison do in Python (and in general)? If I have the following code:

```
def com(a):
    if a > 'banana':
        print 'yes'
    else:
        print 'no'
```

What would make a "greater than" 'banana'? I'm a bit confused by the concept of "comparison". What is being compared?

Comment: in general, that would be a lexicographic comparison. "A"<"B", "AA"<"AB", "ALPHA">"ALPGZ"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/string-comparison-technique-used-by-python has a good answer

Comment: Therefore, is the lexicograhpic order "reversed"? For example, 'zzzzzzz' would be in fact 'greater than' 'banana'?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "reversed", but "zzzz" compares as greater than "banana" in most languages with string comparison

Comment: Lexicographic order is a generalization of alphabetical order. Think the order of words in a dictionary. The comparison tells you which word appears before the other in an English dictionary.

Comment: yes, `'zzzzzzz' > 'banana'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does a lexicographical string comparison.

```
a > b
```

will resolve to:

```
a.__gt__(b)
```

in this case `a` is of type `str`, so it actually calls `str.__gt__(b)` with `a` as the bound instance. "gt" stands for "greater than".

`x.__gt__(y)` returns `True` if `x` is greater than `y` as defined by the function. If `gt` is not defined, it will fall back to using `a.__cmp__(b)`. which returns -1, 0, 1 depending on the comparison result. If `__cmp__` is not defined for type of `a`, this will result in a syntax error.

`str` has a `__gt__` method so it is used for resolving `a > b`. You can supply this method for any of your custom objects.

See docs about rich comparisons [`lt, le, eq, ne, gt, ge`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) and also [`cmp`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp).