# Python string and ordering?

Tags: python, string

Please explain how Python evaluates this string so that one word can be set with a value greater than another word in the string? How is b > n.

```
def not_bad(s):
    n = s.find('not')
    b = s.find('bad')
    if n != -1 and b != -1 and b > n:
      s = s[:n] + 'good' + s[b+3:]
    return s
```

Comment: find returns the position so you're really comparing numbers. http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/string-comparison-technique-used-by-python)

Comment: Try calling your function with _'The sax player hit a wrong note when the band played the lambada'_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b` and `n` are *integers*. The [`str.find()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) returns the position in `str` where the argument was found, or `-1` if the argument was not found.

So, any string `s` containing both `not` and `bad` *and* `bad` follows `not` will do:

```
>>> s = "That's not bad at all"
>>> n = s.find('not')
>>> b = s.find('bad')
>>> n
7
>>> b
11
>>> b > n
True
>>> s[:n] + 'good' + s[b+3:]
"That's good at all"
```

Comment: Thank you - I understand - this was very helpful as an exercise to test right in interpreter. Appreciate your help