# Why does Python allow these compares?

Tags: python, string, syntax, compare, python-3.4

I'm using Python 3.4, wondering why Python allowing these codes;

```
>>> "a">"b"
False
>>> "a"<"b"
True
>>>
```

I think it's maybe about their order in [**ASCII**](http://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) but I will appriciated if someone explain why Python allows like this things. The weird part is, if it was in Python 2x I could understand that but, it's Python 3x. Shouldn't Python throw an SyntaxError?

Edit:  I tried non-Ascii character;

```
>>> "ç">"a"
True
>>>
```

And it's not about ASCII then I understand that, so why Python allowing this?

Comment: Why *shouldn't* it allow it?

Comment: Python 3 allows you to compare the same type of objects. Those would both be unicode strings

Answer (score 3):

[Here's a link that describes your question](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/python_programming/python_ch12s04.html)

The standard comparisons (<, <=, >, >=, ==, !=) apply to strings. These comparisons use the standard character-by-character comparison rules for ASCII or Unicode.

EDIT:

See this other stack overflow post and also look up the ord() function

[String Comparison Technique Used by Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/string-comparison-technique-used-by-python)

Edit!! ord() doesn't work here as 'ç' is not a single byte character

Comment: @PadraicCunningham True, I take back this as correct answer

Comment: @importV, the character by character assessment still holds true, it would make sense that any character like "ç" should be greater than any character like ascii characters that can be stored in a single byte

Comment: Padraic - I should have tested that myself before hand - you are correct in ord() not working.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting names in friend list, sorting search results, searching for best match.
Comparing string is among the most needed operations.