# confused about max() built in function

Tags: python, max

hello I am kind of confused about the max() function, I have the following code:

```
a = '9:30'
b = '10:44'
c = '8:22'
x = max(a, b, c)
print (x)
```

so my question is: why does this return 9:30? and if I were to delete the **a** from inside max it would return 8:22

Comment: Lexicographically, `"9"` is larger than `"1"`

Comment: `a`, `b`, and `c` are not times; they are just strings.

Comment: As @chepner mentions above, you may want to look into using `time` rather than strings. see https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String `a` compares as the biggest because it starts with `9` and the other strings start with `1` and `8`. Python therefore returns `'9:30'` as the maximum value out of those three strings.

Answer (score 2):

As you are doing string comparison the `int` or `ASCII` value of `'9'` is greater than `'8'` and `'1'`. You can see the `int` value of individual char using `ord` built-in function.

```
>>> ord('9')
57
>>> ord('1')
49
>>> ord('8')
56
```

And as Python does comparison in [lexicographical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/string-comparison-technique-used-by-python) manner(from left to right each char). It finds value of `'9'` greater. And if you delete `'9'` if finds `'8'`'s value greater than `'1'`.

One way to achieve could be :-

```
a = '9:30'
b = '10:44'
c = '8:22'
d = '10:55'

print max([a, b, c, d], key=lambda x: map(int, x.split(':')))
```

Comment: Better remove the `[0]` or it will compare `10:30` and `10:45` as equal.

Comment: Also, `lambda i: int(i)` is the same as just `int`.

Comment: Yeah but it will return a list of int value. [10,45] and [10, 55] which will return [10, 55] as greater value.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of that `max` function will find the max value  lexicographicaly , you can use a proper key for `max` function to convert the hour and min to `int`.

```
>>> l=[a,b,c]
>>> max(l,key=lambda d :map(int, d.split(":")))
'10:44'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's arguments are strings, it is returning the string that is latest in alphabetic order.

Answer (score 0):

it is comparing strings, and, as such, it starts by comparing the first character, and then, if that character is the same, moves on to the next and then the next etc etc.

So '9:30' is returned because 9 > 8 > 1. If you want "10:44" to return, then you should use the `datetime` module, unless you want to write custom code for that

edit: and sniped by people who type faster!

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings, not numbers or times. As such, it compares the strings by their first character (and if those are equal, by the second, and so on), and the first character of `"9:30"` is the highest.

If you want to compare the times, you can `split` the string at the `:`symbol, `map` the parts to integers and compare those, using an according `key` function.

```
x = max([a, b, c], key=lambda s: map(int, s.split(":")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it so you can just use the regular `max` function. First, pad the strings so that `"9"` becomes `"09"` and `"10"` stays `"10"`. You can use `str.zfill` for this:

```
a = '9:30'
b = '10:44'
c = '8:22'
a, b, c = map(lambda s: s.zfill(5), (a, b, c))
```

Now, they will be what you want lexicographically!

```
print(max([a, b, c]))
10:44
```

You only have to pad them once, but you will be stuck with:

```
print(min([a, b, c]))
08:22
```