# python won't count two digit number as highest value

Tags: python

List = [name, lines.split(":")[1]]  Latest_scores = (lines.split(":")[1][-7:])
Highscore = max(latest_scores)
Print(highscore)

Out of: 9,10,2,
It says the highestvalue is 9, not 10 as if it is ignoring the two digit number.

Comment: Convert them to integers before comparing:  `max(latest_scores, key=int)`.

Comment: You might want to add an actual code snippet that contains everything needed to run, and demonstrates your problem. However, based on the fact that you are using `lines`, I will assume that you read it from a file, in which case the values are of type `str` and not of type `int`.

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/string-comparison-technique-used-by-python

Comment: It is comparing strings, not integers. As suggested before, convert them to integer. Use `nums = [int(num) for num in Latest_scores]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should convert the scores to integers, e.g. with `map(int, Latest_scores)`. Strings are compared in alphabetic order, where 9 comes last and therefore is the maximum.

EDIT: From your comments it seems that `Latest_scores` is just a string. That would mean you're trying to find a maximum in a string. The `max` function then returns the "highest" character in the string. To make this work correctly, you have to split the string by the `,` character:

```
Latest_scores = lines.split(":")[1][-7:].split(",")
Highscore = max(map(int, Latest_scores))
Print(Highscore)
```

Comment: So where would you write that in the program?

Comment: That's up to you, I suggest putting it into the max() function call on line 2

Comment: Would it work then if I wrote: highscore = max(map(int, Latest_scores))

Comment: Yes. But don't ask, try it!

Comment: It doesn't work, it just says invalid literal for base 10 something

Comment: Oh, that looks like there are some non-numeric characters in the `Latest_scores` variable. Could you post its content (edit your question)?

Comment: Umm... I meant the content of the `Latest_scores` variable.