# String comparison, less than sign

Tags: python

I have two strings, `Right` and `banana`. When I compare, `Right < banana` the result is given as `True`. I understand that Python compares letter by letter.

(1) But then these two strings are not in the same length. How would this be possible?
(2) I looked up the `ASCII`, then I tried the following: `R < b`, and the result is `True;` `i < a`, and the result is `False`, and so on. Clearly we have `False` and `True` in comparing letter by letter, `Right < banana`. How does **Python** determine that the final result is `True`?

I did look up a few sources online, and couldn't find answer. I've just started to learn Python as my first programming language, so maybe I didn't know where to look...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/string-comparison-technique-used-by-python

Comment: The search term you're looking for is "lexicographical ordering".

Answer (score 5):

Python compares sequences naively. Since "R" is less than "b", "Right" is less than "banana".

Comment: In the ascii table, you first have all uppercase letters, then all lowercase letters. So r > b, but R < b.

Answer (score 0):

Python uses the ASCII/Byte/Unicode point value to compare chars
For example

```
def python_less_than(s1, s2):
    'a function that acts like the way python compare strings'
    return [ord(c) for c in s1] < [ord(c) for c in s2]
```