# Simple Guessing Game not working

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, tkinter

This is supposed to be a guessing game. If the user submits a number that is higher than the pre-set value (which is 10), it will say go lower. And if the user submits a lower number, it will say go higher. The problem I'm facing is that it only tells me to go higher with every integer or even string I type in. Any clue what the problem might be?

Also, the reason I turned 10 into a string is because it gives me an error if it's an integer.

```
from tkinter import *

# Simple guessing game
window = Tk()

def number():
    if typed == key:
        print("This is the correct key")
    elif typed > key:
        print("Go lower!")
    else:
        print("Go higher!")

e = Entry(window)
e.pack()

key = str(10)
typed = e.get()

b = Button(window, text="Submit", command=number)
b.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You never update values of `typed` and `key` They are computed once and never changed in any kind of callback. Also, comparing strings will lead you to unexpected behaviour. See [String Comparison Technique Used by Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/string-comparison-technique-used-by-python) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the value on each submit and check or else it will stay constant. The reason why it did not work is because you assigned `typed` to `e.get()` on program start, which is an empty string. You need to update it on every click, or put `typed` inside the function.

You also need to make `key` an integer, and convert the entry value into an integer, or else you're lexicographically comparing strings. Also, you can add a try/except to handle if the user does not enter an integer, as shown below.

I would personally pass the entry's value into the function and on click use a lambda to process the check:

```
from tkinter import *

# Simple guessing game
window = Tk()

def number(num): # Passing in string instead of using typed
    try:
        intNum = int(num) # Here we convert num to integer for comparison
        if intNum == key:
            print("This is the correct key")
        elif intNum > key:
            print("Go lower!")
        else:
            print("Go higher!")
    except ValueError: # If user doesn't enter a convertable integer, then print "Not an integer!"
        print("Not an integer!")

e = Entry(window)
e.pack()

key = 10 # Key is an integer here!

b = Button(window, text="Submit", command=lambda: number(e.get())) # Here's a lambda where we pass in e.get() to check
b.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

So now it will pass the value in, then compare instead of using `typed`. `lambda: number(num)` just allows the passing of an argument in the command argument. Here's a link to [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) regarding lambdas. Without lambdas, [here's](http://hastebin.com/upedigiyow.py) a hastebin demonstrating without function arguments.

Comment: Hey, I tried this code but it gives "Go lower" when i type in any number between 2 and 9

Comment: Yes it works. I'm wondering is there a way of writing this code without using lambda?

Comment: @user3081954 [Sure there is](http://hastebin.com/upedigiyow.py), just have `e.get()` inside the function.

Comment: Alright so to sum up: "typed" needs to be defined inside the function otherwise it will have an empty value at program startup.

Comment: @user3081954 Yes. Inside the function, it will then get the entry value every time when button is clicked, allowing it to compare correctly