# Lexicographical comparison when 1 string is shorter

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Strings are compared lexicographically.

In this example the first 2 corresponding 9s will be compared but after that what is compared against 1?

```
>>> '99' > '991'
False
```

Comment: Nothing, size matters.

Comment: It seems the [*"until either sequence is exhausted"*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types) part explains it (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4806946/3832970).

Comment: What Wiktor said: "If one sequence is an initial sub-sequence of the other, the shorter sequence is the smaller (lesser) one. "

Comment: In a dictionary, would you expect "dental" to come before "dent"? Lexicographical order in programming is hopefully consistent with the natural lexicographical order.