# occasional variable comparison error in python

Tags: python, comparison

In the below program the result of the if statement near the end is occasionally wrong but I cannot see a pattern in it. I have debugged it as much as possible but I cannot find my error. I'm sorry for the large amount of code but I don't know where the error is in that code all I know is that it is somewhere in the code below.

Help would be much appreciated!

I am not hugely experienced in python so please explain any answers in detail

```
for i in range(1,10):
import random

Cards = list(range(0,8))
print("shuffling...")
random.shuffle(Cards)
#print(Cards)

PlayerCards = []
ComputerCards = []
CardsLen = int(len(Cards)) / 2

for i in range(int(CardsLen)):
    PlayerCards.append(Cards[0])
    del Cards[0]
    ComputerCards.append(Cards[0])
    del Cards[0]

#print(PlayerCards)
#print(ComputerCards)



Ab5s = ['9', '12', '1', '10', '5', '6', '6', '8']

#print(Ab5s)

Ab5sS = sorted(Ab5s, key = int)
#print(Ab5sS)


AbNames = ['Magic', 'Cunning', 'Courage', 'Wisdom', 'Temper']
#print(AbNames)

Ab5Name = AbNames[4]
AbNamesDict = {5: Ab5s}



PlayerCardNum = PlayerCards[0]
ComputerCardNum = ComputerCards[0]



PlayerCardAb5 = Ab5s[PlayerCardNum]
ComputerCardAb5 = Ab5s[ComputerCardNum]


PlayerAbVal = Ab5s[PlayerCardNum]
ComputerAbVal = Ab5s[ComputerCardNum]

#print(PlayerAbVal)
#print(ComputerAbVal)


while True:
    try:
        PlayerAbUse = "Temper" #input("Which ability do you want to use ")
        PlayerAbUse = PlayerAbUse.title()
        PlayerAbNum = (AbNames.index(PlayerAbUse) + 1)
        break

    except ValueError:
        print("error")
        continue


AbList = AbNamesDict[PlayerAbNum]    
PlayerAbVal = (AbList)[PlayerCardNum]
ComputerAbVal = (AbList)[ComputerCardNum]

#print(PlayerAbVal)
#print(ComputerAbVal)

print("Player has " + PlayerCardAb5 + " " + Ab5Name)
print("Computer has " + ComputerAbVal + " " + Ab5Name)

WonCards = []


#This is where I believe it is going wrong

if PlayerAbVal < ComputerAbVal:
    Winner = 0
else:
    if PlayerAbVal == ComputerAbVal:
        Winner = 2
    else:
        Winner = 1

WonCards.append(PlayerCards.pop(0))
WonCards.append(ComputerCards.pop(0))



if Winner == 0:
    print("Computer Win ")
    while len(WonCards) > 0:
        ComputerCards.append(WonCards.pop(0))
    print("")
else:
    if Winner == 1:
        print("Player Win ")
        while len(WonCards) > 0:
            PlayerCards.append(WonCards.pop(0))
        print("")

    else:
        print("Draw ")
        Winner = random.randint(1,2)
```

Comment: What exactly is this code supposed to do? What am I looking for? It's better if you isolate the code that you suspect is giving problems :-)

Comment: `for i in range(1,10): import random`. What?

Comment: @mangoHero1 The code is part of a top trumps game and sometimes it give the wrong answer for the winner

Comment: Could you please provide full traceback of the error so we can better help you.

Comment: Is this Python 2? Your list `Ab5sS` contains strings. Python 2 will allow you to compare `int` and `str` with `>` etc but the output is nonsensical compared to what you want. Get rid of the quotes on each number in `Ab5sS`. The fact that it is sometimes right is just coincidental.

Comment: python doesnt give me an error message but its result is wrong

Comment: @roganjosh the print statements are followed by parentheses, so this is python3

Comment: @mangoHero1 that in itself does not provide anything conclusive `print('something')` is also valid in Python 2.

Comment: @roganjosh this is python 3, sorry i forgot to say

Comment: In that case I'm out of ideas. It's not easy to follow your code (names like `Ab5sS` and similar variations aren't helpful for understanding), you should try and boil this down to an isolated issue. In doing that, you might find the answer yourself.

Comment: If you run the code and look at the results sometimes when Computer has it higher than the player it says the player wins and vice versa

Comment: I'm not convinced you are running Python 3. Please put `import sys` at the top of your file and then have `print(sys.version)`. Copy/paste that output back here. If I convert those strings to ints, it works fine for me. In other words, I can replicate your issue perfectly in Python 2 and it's easily fixed. **Regardless**; there's no reason to have those numbers as strings, you can solve the concatenation problem in your `prints` by casting them to strings there or using `format()` (which is the better way)

Comment: @roganjosh 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 17:54:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]

Comment: @roganjosh that appears to have worked! Thanks alot if you post it as an answer I will mark it as accepted. Also, how do you use format()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify your `if` statement to force the type to be `int`'s. (use `if..elif..else` for more pythonicness)

```
if int(PlayerAbVal) < int(ComputerAbVal):
   Winner = 0
elif int(PlayerAbVal) == int(ComputerAbVal):
   Winner = 2
else:
   Winner = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I was going to accept @roganjosh 's solution but this is better for me as it allows me to import the list from a file

Comment: This does work but there is no reason to have the list as strings in the first place, so it seems counter-intuitive to me to work around that fact.

Comment: @user8430559 ok, that wasn't actually in your question. Had I known that, I would have shown you the quick conversion. I will edit my answer, regardless of which you choose to accept, because you shouldn't really be coding around this issue rather than addressing it at source.

Comment: sorry @roganjosh I was attempting to simplify what I was posting, I admit I didn't do a very good job

Comment: @user8430559 it's fine; asking your first question is daunting :) I added the edit to my answer anyway so you can see how to do the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are comparing strings, not numerical values. My initial thought was that you were in Python 2, but actually this failure can also be explained by [lexicographical ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/string-comparison-technique-used-by-python)

Change your list `Ab5sS` to contain integers. So:

```
Ab5s = [9, 12, 1, 10, 5, 6, 6, 8]
```

To fix your `print`s, cast to string there e.g.:

```
print("Player has " + str(PlayerCardAb5) + " " + Ab5Name)
```

Or, better, use `format()`:

```
print("Player has {} {}".format(PlayerCardAb5, Ab5Name))
```

As you mentioned in another comment, your issue is that you're reading strings as values from a file. This doesn't stop you from converting the values to `int`; the easiest way is probably just a list comprehension:

```
Ab5s = ['9', '12', '1', '10', '5', '6', '6', '8']
Ab5s = [int(item) for item in Ab5s]
```

There's other ways, such as `map`, but I think that's [falling out of favour](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196).

```
Ab5s = map(float, Ab5s)
```