# Python 3x - Size of a string

Tags: string, python-3.x

When I run this code, the value of H is false. I used `sys.getsizeof()` function and `S5 = 29` and `S6 = 33` came out. I don't get it why `S5 >S 6` ?

```
S5 = "ants"
S6 = "anteater"

H = S5 < S6
print( "Value of H:", H )
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are compared lexicographically using the numeric equivalents (the result of the built-in function ord()) of their characters. Unicode and 8-bit strings are fully interoperable in this behavior.

For more details check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/string-comparison-technique-used-by-python)

Comment: Ohh thanks a lot. I googled it but I could not find any proper explanation about that.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? Are you trying to calculate the size of both strings? To calculate the size of a string, do `myLength = len("myString")`. You can then add the result from both strings if you wish to do so.

Hope this helps.