# Checking strings and determine which is alphabetically smaller

Tags: python, string

How do I perform the comparison between two strings to determine which is **alphabetically smaller**?

Example, if I have strings `'aberr'` and `'aftward'` how do I determine which is **alphabetically smaller**? Another example would be `'beast'` and `'best'`.

Do I have to make the strings into it's ascii representation such as:

```
ascii a + ascii b + ascii e...
```

Comment: Python string support comparaison: `'a' < 'b'` equals `True`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String comparison technique used by Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/string-comparison-technique-used-by-python)

Comment: Is there some difference between "alphabetically smaller" and "lexicographically smaller"? Python does the latter automatically. Are you worried about capitalization or accents or something similar? Are you using a collating sequence other than Unicode?

Comment: you can compare the .lower() versions if you are worried about caps

Comment: Unless you mean lexicographically, you need to know a few things to start: character encoding, language/culture/locale, and desired case sensitivity; Fixed ones or user's settings or choice?

Answer (score 3):

You can do string comparison in Python:

```
>>> min('aberr', 'aftward') 
'aberr'
```

and

```
>>> min('beast', 'best')
'beast'
```

**EDIT**

As [Grady Player](https://stackoverflow.com/users/593382/grady-player) points out, `A` come after `z`. You'll need to lower the string like this:

```
>>> min('aaaa', 'Bbbb')
'Bbbb'
>>> min('aaaa'.lower(), 'Bbbb'.lower())
'aaaa'
```

If you want to keep the string like it was, you'll need to use the `key` attribute of `min`:

```
>>> min('Aaaa', 'bbbb', key=lambda s: s.lower())
'Aaaa'
```

You can also sort them:

```
>>> sorted(['Aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cbaaa', 'bcaaa'], key=lambda s: s.lower())
['Aaaa', 'bbbb', 'bcaaa', 'cbaaa']
```

Comment: `>>> min('aberr', 'Aftward')

'Aftward'`

Comment: Yes, you may need to lower both for comparison. I'll add that. Thanks.