# What does passing str.lower as the key to list.sort do?

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
def Sorting(lst):
    lst.sort(key=str.lower)
    lst.sort(key=len)
    return lst

lst = ["Ronit", "Dan", "Yael"]
print Sorting(lst)
```

This code sorts the list alphabetically then by length. I was wondering why is it "lower"? is it not going to work with upper case letters? what is it for?

Comment: Have a look at [String comparison technique used by Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4806911/8944057).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It performs *case insensitive sorting*.

Let's modify your example a bit, to include another entry "dan":

```
lst = ['Ronit', 'Dan', 'dan']
```

Naturally, you'd expect "Dan" and "dan" to occur together. But they don't, because of the properties of string ordering. Instead, a plain `list.sort` call will give you:

```
lst.sort()
print(lst)
['Dan', 'Ronit', 'dan']
```

On the other hand, specifying `str.lower` gives you this:

```
lst.sort(key=str.lower)
print(lst)
['Dan', 'dan', 'Ronit']
```

Here, the original list elements are sorted with respect to their lowercased equivalents.

The second `list.sort` call with `len` should now be self-explanatory, assuming you understand what `key` does (yes, sort by length).

---

To understand why the first is needed before the second, consider another contrived example:

```
lst = ['Ronit', 'Dan', 'ram', 'dan']
```

First, consider just `key=len`:

```
lst.sort(key=len)
print(lst)
['Dan', 'ram', 'dan', 'Ronit']
```

That "ram" looks out of place here. THIS IS PRECISELY WHY WE HAVE THE FIRST STEP. Now, adding in that step makes our output a lot more sensible.

```
lst.sort(key=str.lower)
lst.sort(key=len)

print(lst)
['Dan', 'dan', 'ram', 'Ronit']
```

So, in conclusion, the elements are ordered first case-insensitively, and then ordered by length.

Comment: Unrelated but this seems to be trying to sort the strings in shortlex order, however this relies on `sorted()` being stable, which is what is guaranteed by the manual.