# What does a list sort(key=str.lower) do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Can you explain the second line with explain?

```
spam = ['a', 'z', 'A', 'Z']
spam.sort(key=str.lower)
print(spam)
```

Comment: It does case-insensitive in-place sort of the list. The `key` argument is a callable which operates on the items and returns the object that will be used for sorting. In this case it returns the string converted to lower case.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that because elements `'a'` and `'A'` for example have equal keys returned by the `str.lower` callable, their relative order in the sorted list will be undefined.

Comment: These things are [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list.sort#list.sort)

Comment: @alaniwi `list.sort` is a stable sort

Comment: @donkopotamus Thank you, I stand corrected. Translation for OP: pairs like `'A'` and `'a'` that are equal when compared case-insensitively will appear in the same order that they did originally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does passing str.lower as the key to list.sort do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50498997/what-does-passing-str-lower-as-the-key-to-list-sort-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
spam.sort(key=str.lower)
```

is sorting your `spam` list alphabetically as it's case-insensitive. So if you change your 3rd line to

```
print(spam)
```

you get

```
['a', 'A', 'z', 'Z']
```

without the `key` in your `sort` the sorted list would be

```
['A', 'Z', 'a', 'z']
```

Comment: The third line makes sense if the source was originally an example for an interactive interpreter

Comment: still confused can you explain with an example - spam.sort(key=str.lower)

Answer (score 1):

`spam` is a list, and lists in python have a built-in `sort` function that changes the list order from low to high values.

e.g.

```
Nums = [2,1,3]
Nums.sort()
Nums
```

Output

```
[1,2,3]
```

The `key` parameter of `sort` is a function that is applied to each element of the list before comparison in the sorting algorithm.  `str.lower` is a function that returns characters in lowercase.

e.g.

```
A -> a
```

So, the second line sorts `spam` by the lowercase values of its elements.

Which should result in

```
[a,A,z,Z]
```

Answer (score 0):

`spam.sort(key=str.lower)`

`sort()` is a default function for sorting in python and it can take some sorting function as a parameter.
here `key = str.lower` is the sorting function which means that it should parse every string to lower case before sorting.
which means that this is case in sensitive search.

Answer (score 0):

It performs case insensitive sorting.

Let's modify your example a bit, to include another entry "a":

```
spam = ['a', 'z', 'A', 'Z','a']
```

Naturally, you'd expect first "`a`" and second "`a`" to occur together. But they don't when you give `key=str.lower`, because of the properties of string ordering. Instead, a plain list.sort call will give you:

```
spam = ['a', 'z', 'A', 'Z','a']
spam.sort()
print(spam)

output
['A', 'Z', 'a', 'a', 'z']
```

On the other hand, specifying str.lower gives you this:

```
spam = ['a', 'z', 'A', 'Z','a']
spam.sort(key=str.lower)
print(spam)

output:
['a', 'A', 'a', 'z', 'Z']
```

Here, the original list elements are sorted with respect to their lowercased equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when str.lower is done then the data in spam becomes 'a','z','a','z' due to which when sorting is  done then both 'a' will come first and then 'z' ... but as the actual spam is not altered and only while sorting the data's case was changed so you get the output as 'a' 'A' 'z' 'Z' ..
same result you will get when you do key=str.upper.

Answer (score -1):

I had never programming in Python, but what i see:

- spam is array of strings
- spam.sort = sorts array, key - is current value, you can do smth.
- str.lower - means you will translate each string to lower case (L => l)
- and last line means you returns that array (maybe...)