# While-loop guessing number

Tags: python

Create an input field "Guess my age". 
If the age is correct print 'you are correct', 
if the age is lower than your age print 'I am older than that', 
if the entered age is higher than your age print ' I am not THAT old !!!' 
Use a while loop to ask for your age until the correct age is entered.

Here is my code so far:

```
answer = input('Guess my age')
   while answer != "22":
      if answer > "22":
         print("I am not THAT old!!")
         input ('Guess my age')
      if answer < "22":
         print("I am older than that")
         input('Guess my age')
   print("You are correct!")
```

If I enter "21" in the input box, for example, it will return saying "I am older than that" which is correct, but when it prompts for another number to be entered, say I put "45" it will continue to say "I am older than that", which is wrong and should say "I am not THAT old!!", and vice versa

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you are NOT updating `answer`. I think every time asked for input, it should be assigned to `answer`

Comment: @student is correct

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Comment: It still shouldn't work how are you comparing values of strings to eachother?

Comment: @vash_the_stampede yes,  I think the other **error** would be comparing string. Try `print("100"<"50")`

Comment: @student whats weird right now or I'm sleepy check this , `'100'<'50' >>> True` right but `'100' < '1' >>> False` Now its wierd because all of his evaluations with using strings actually work.... O.o im going to bed lol what is going on

Comment: @student `'21' < '22' >>> True`  and `'21' > '22' >>> False` I know its not coincidence so what is happening

Comment: I think it compares character by character, you can check the discussion, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/string-comparison-technique-used-by-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating answer, and you are not making answer answer an int here:

```
answer = int(input('Guess my age'))
   while answer != 22:
      if answer > 22:
         print("I am not THAT old!!")
         answer = int(input ('Guess my age'))
      if answer < 22:
         print("I am older than that")
         answer = int(input('Guess my age'))
   print("You are correct!")
```

Comment: Huh, I didn't know you could do less than for strings