# Select DataFrame rows for datetime which are stored in object column

Tags: python, pandas

also the following question is quite similiar to this question: [Select DataFrame rows between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates)

I wonder how I can select the rows of a dataframe, if my dataframe column is no datetime column. The above solutions always converting the rows to a datetime column, and I don't want to do that for a later process.
 Right now I have the following dataframe:

```
columnA
01.10.2018
02.10.2018
.....
```

and `df.dtypes`is `object`.

My idea would be to use  `.loc`:

```
df.loc[df['columnA'] >= "02.10.2019"]
```

which could lead to the outcome:

```
columnA
02.10.2018
```

Does this work for this object column? Or do I missing something? I really don't want to convert it to a datetime column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot working for most strings formats, because strings are compared [lexicographically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/string-comparison-technique-used-by-python) (thanks @Jon Clements).

Only if has string in format `YYYYMMDD` comparing with string working correctly:

```
print ('02.10.2018' >= '03.10.2017')
False
print ('20181002' >= '20171003')
True
```

So the best is convert values to datetimes in pandas, if need processing them.

Comment: I taught the same, let's see if there is another workaround

Comment: @PV8 - yop, unfortunately not for strings datetimes