# Python Pandas date time drop row if older

Tags: python, pandas

```
 LastUpdate            TS_UPDATE
0  2020-02-02  2019-10-30 15:27:20
6  2020-02-02  2019-10-30 15:27:14
8  2020-02-02  2019-10-30 15:27:07
9  2020-02-02  2019-10-30 15:27:07
10 2020-02-02  2019-10-30 15:27:07
11 2020-02-02  2019-10-30 15:27:05
12 2020-02-02  2019-10-30 15:27:04
13 2020-02-02  2019-10-30 15:27:03
14 2020-02-02  2019-10-30 15:27:03
15 2020-02-02  2019-10-30 15:27:02
```

How can I check if the `LastUpdate` is newer than `TS_UPDATE`?  OR probably better: 
if `TS_UPDATE` is OLDER than `LastUpdate`
if that isnt the case -> drop row.

Can anyone help me out?

Is it possible to do by boolean (`> / <`)?

```
 for row in df:
    if df["LastUpdate"][row] < df["TS_UPDATE"][row]:
        #drop row
```

Comment: Is the data already in datetime format?

Comment: This seems rather basic, have you read the Pandas docs?

Comment: yes it is already in datetime format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is `string`, you would get an answer for the `> or <` comparison and [here's how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/string-comparison-technique-used-by-python). If all the data in your dataframe is formatted in the way you have shown, the comparison should work. Instead of the for loop you can just do

```
new_df = df[df["LastUpdate"] < df["TS_UPDATE"]]
```

However, if you really want to compare the numbers, you can use pandas' `pd.to_datetime` function. This will transform the strings to `datetime` format which supports many numerical operations

```
df['LUdt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['LastUpdate'])
df['TSdt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TS_UPDATE'])
new_df = df[df['LUdt'] > df['TUdt']]
```

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way is to just keep the relevant rows:

```
resul = df[df["LastUpdate"] >= df["TS_UPDATE"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `query` method:

```
df.query("LastUpdate>=TS_UPDATE")
```

Very compact, SQL-like syntax.

If You insist on iteration:

```
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    if r.LastUpdate < r.TS_UPDATE:
        df.drop(i, inplace = True)
```