# How does the max function work in Tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
t=('ali','rahul','ram')
```

In the above code, when I run the max function,

```
print(max(t))
```

this is the output I get :
ram

Why do I get Ram and not Ali?

Comment: And why should you get Ali?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String comparison technique used by Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/string-comparison-technique-used-by-python)

Answer (score 3):

`max()` will return the largest element, either by comparing numbers or comparing strings lexicographically (the same way words are ordered in a dictonary -- the book one, not the python `dict()`):

```
>>> max((1,2,3))
3
>>> max(('b','a','c'))
'c'
>>>
```