# Question about comparing characters with the > or < logical operators

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is `'a'>'b' = False` and `'a'>'A' = True` in python?
anybody with a clear explanation of this.
I tried searching up, but couldn't really find an appropriate clear explanation.

Comment: What are the values of `a`, `b`, and `A`?

Comment: The letter frmo the alphabet or variable that you set ?

Comment: I think OP means strings

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/string-comparison-technique-used-by-python

Comment: In the ASCII character set, capital letters come first.  So `'A'` has a lower character number than `'a'`.  And obviously `'b'` comes after `'a'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hello Welcome to Stack Overflow,

You mean:

```
'a' > 'b'
Out[3]: False
'a'>'A'
Out[4]: True
```

As this is based on the ascii values of 'a' = 97 and 'A' = 65. You can find the ascii values using `ord()` function.

```
ord('a')
Out[7]: 97
ord('b')
Out[8]: 98
ord('A')
Out[9]: 65
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the ASCII table and notice that uppercase letters are in the range 65-90 and lowercase letters are in the range 97-122. That's the default coding used for Python.

[ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You should learn about ASCII values. [Click here to learn about ASCII value](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html)

Some char and their ASCII value is given below:

**'a': 97**

**'b': 98**

**'A': 65**

**'B': 66.**

so, when you are doing **'a'>'b'** it means **97>98** which is False.

Similarly, when you are doing **'a'>'A'** it means **97>65** which is True.