# Compare string and integer in same if statement

Tags: python, conditional-statements, operators

I have a program that takes input from the user. I want to display an invalid option message if the input is a string or it is not a number between 1 to 4. I want to check all these 3 conditions in a single if statement.

```
ask_option = input("Your option: ")

if int(ask_option) != int and (int(ask_option) < 1 or int(ask_option) > 4):
    print("Not a valid option")
```

I feel the int(ask_option) != int is incorrect. But is it possible to fulfill all these 3 in a single if statement?

My code fulfills the criteria to choose between 1-4 but doesn't work to check string input. Please help

Comment: I think you're expecting too much to handle all this in a single `if` statement.  Just do the `int()` in its own statement within a try/except block to catch the case where the input wasn't numeric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input()` will always return a string unless you explicity convert it. So using `ask_option = int(input("Your option: "))` will already satisfy checking if `ask_option` is an integer as an exception will be raised otherwise.

As for evaluating the integer, you can accomplish this in a single line such as:

```
if not 1 <= ask_option <= 4:
   print("Not a valid option")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to convert string input into an int, the program will throw ValueError.

```
ask_option = input("Your option: ")

try:
   val = int(ask_option)
   if val <= 1 or val => 4:
    print("Not a valid option!")
except ValueError:
   print("Not a valid option!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ask_option = input("Your option: ")
if len(ask_option) != 1 or ask_option < '1' or ask_option > '4':
    print("Not a valid option")
else:
    print( "valid option")
```

Edit:

OP: "I want to display an invalid option message if the input is a string or it is not a number between 1 to 4."

Therefore we need to accept values ranging from `1 - 4`

We know that `input()` accepts everything as a string

so in the `if` statement

first condition: `len(ask_option) != 1`

We invalidate any string whose length is `not equal` to `1` ( since we need to accept values ranging from `1-4` which are of a `length 1` )

And now we are left to deal with the `input` value whose length is just `1` which could be anything and will be checked with the next 2 conditions.

second and third condition: `ask_option < '1' or ask_option > '4'`

We do `string` comparison ( which is done using their ASCII values )

more on `string` comparison: [String comparison technique used by Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/string-comparison-technique-used-by-python)

I would not recommend using this approach since it's hard to tell what it does on the first look, so it's better if you use `try` `except` instead as suggested in other answers.

See this solution as just a different approach to solve OP's problem ( but not recommended to implement. )

Comment: Although this piece of code might solve OP's problem, you should explain what id does exactly in a few words and how it is fixing the issue.