# python3 string comparison like '9' < '10'

Tags: python, string, comparison

I read this question [String comparison technique used by Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4806911/11327104).

But, i don't know exactly why the comparison '9' < '10'  is `False`.
Did this happen because '9' is bigger than '1'? because python's string comparison is lexicographic?

Comment: string comparison is lexicographic and char `"9"` comes after char `"1"`

Comment: you got it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Python grabs the first character in the strings and compares them. In this case it starts by comparing if `9` is less than `1`. Since it's not, `False` is returned. Comparisons are done using the [character codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters). (To save you some time looking it up, 1-9 are indeed in numerical order. Something to be careful about is the capital letters are before the lowercase ones, so `'B' < 'a'` returns `True`.)

If the comparison were equal, it would move on to the next character and so on.

You can use [isnumeric](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) to check if you're comparing 2 numbers, and if you are then change the strings to numbers before comparing.

```
if a.isnumeric() and b.isnumeric():
    if float(a) < float(b):
```

Answer (score 0):

In lexicographic order "10" comes before "9" that is why it is returning False. If you did

```
"10" < "9"
```

You would get True because the string "10" comes before the string "9".