# Why does comparing number as a string in Python doesn't work as intended?

Tags: python

```
if "16" > "13": print("a")
if "8" > "15": print("b")
```

This code will print "a b" in the console. Why does the first statement work as intended and the second doesn't?

Comment: Strings are compared in alphabetical order; the fact that all of your characters are digits doesn't magically cause the strings to behave like numbers.

Comment: Define "intended" ?

Comment: more about in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/string-comparison-technique-used-by-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, the `>` and `<` operators are implemented using a class's underlying `__cmp__` magic function, the logic of which differs by class.

The logic for numbers is to compare the signed value, e.g. `12.6 >10` is true, and `-4 > -33.02` is true, in the normal mathematical sense.

The logic for strings is to compare each character, left to right, based on the ordinal value of each character, e.g. `'apple' > 'banana'` is false because `ord('a')` is 97 and `ord('b')` is 98, so `97 > 98` is false. Likewise `'8 > '15'` is true because `ord('8')` is 56, and and `ord('1')` is 49, so `56 > 49` is true.

Python doesn't convert strings-of-digits to numbers before comparing.

Answer (score 0):

Because `8` (first digit) is greater than `1` (first digit)... you are comparing strings, not integers.

Do you want to compare numbers? Do the same without the quotes:

```
if 16 > 13: print("a")
if 8 > 15: print("b")
```