# What's the logic behind locating elements using letters in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file. I load it in pandas dataframe. Now, I am practicing the loc method. This CSV file contains a list of James bond movies and I am passing letters in the loc method. I could not interpret the result shown.

```
bond = pd.read_csv("jamesbond.csv", index_col = "Film")
bond.sort_index(inplace = True)
bond.head(3)

bond.loc["A": "I"]
```

The result for the above code is:

[image: A to I]

```
bond.loc["a": "i"]
```

And the result for the above code is:

[image: a to i]

What is happening here? I could not understand. Please someone help me to understand the properties of pandas.

Following is the file:

[image: Jamesbond File]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dataframe uses the first column ("Film") as an index when it is imported (because of the option `index_col = "Film"`). The column contains the name of each film stored as a string, and they all start with a capital letter. `bond.loc["A":"I"]` returns all films where the index is greater than or equal to "A" and less than or equal to "I" (pandas slices are [upper-bound inclusive](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-endpoints-are-inclusive)), which by the [rules of string comparison in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/string-comparison-technique-used-by-python) includes all films beginning with "A"-"H", and would also include a film called "I" if there was one. If you enter e.g. `"A" <= "b" <="I"` in the python prompt you will see that lower-case letters are not within the range, because [`ord("b") > ord("I")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord).

If you wrote `bond.index = bond.index.str.lower()` that would change the index to lower case and you could search films using e.g. `bond["a":"i"]` (but `bond["A":"I"]` would no longer return any films).

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame.loc["A":"I"]` returns the rows that start with the letter in that range - from what I can see and tried to reproduce. Might you attach the data?

Comment: Could not attach .csv file. But, I have added the image of full data.