# Sort a list that contains both strings and integers (Python)

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort a list of tuples which contain (string, integer, integer). The first value of these tuples can be any string (for example '$', or a numeric string such as '9'). The goal is to sort according to the first element of these tuples, if the comparison occurs between two identical strings I sort according to the second element. I tried the following approach but it turned out to be unsuccessful. Solutions?

```
array = [('$', 0, 0), ('3', 3, 3), ('7', 5, 6), ('15', 6, 9), ('5', 7, 11), ('17', 8, 13), ('18', 9, 16), ('19', 10, 18), ('16', 11, 20)]
sorted_array = sorted(array, key=lambda x:(x[0], int(x[1])))
print(sorted_array)
```

Output:

```
[('$', 0, 0), ('3', 3, 3), ('7', 5, 6), ('15', 6, 9), ('5', 7, 11), ('17', 8, 13), ('18', 9, 16), ('19', 10, 18), ('16', 11, 20)]
```

I want to get:

```
[('$', 0, 0), ('3', 3, 3), ('5', 7, 11), ('7', 5, 6), ('15', 6, 9), ('16', 11, 20), ('17', 8, 13), ('18', 9, 16), ('19', 10, 18)]
```

Comment: String comparisons don't work that way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4806946/13111190  You'll have to define a more complex function for the key.

Comment: What are your rules? You can use `natsort.natsorted` to sort `'7'` before `'15'`, but this will push `$` at the end.

Comment: I want a sort that sorts strings based on their lexicographical order and numeric strings based on numerical order. @mozway

Comment: Then check my answer, might be what you want ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `natsort` (natural sorting) and `str.isdigit` you can sort numbers naturally while keeping non numbers first. But the more general rule you might expect is unclear.

```py
from natsort import natsorted 

array = [('$', 0, 0), ('3', 3, 3), ('7', 5, 6), ('15', 6, 9), ('5', 7, 11), ('17', 8, 13), ('18', 9, 16), ('19', 10, 18), ('16', 11, 20)]
sorted_array = natsorted(array, key=lambda x:(x[0].isdigit(), x))
print(sorted_array)
```

Output:

```
[('$', 0, 0), ('3', 3, 3), ('5', 7, 11), ('7', 5, 6), ('15', 6, 9), ('16', 11, 20), ('17', 8, 13), ('18', 9, 16), ('19', 10, 18)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get that result with a regular sort if you right justify the string component in the sort key.

```
array = [('$', 0, 0), ('3', 3, 3), ('7', 5, 6), ('15', 6, 9), 
         ('5', 7, 11), ('17', 8, 13), ('18', 9, 16), ('19', 10, 18), 
         ('16', 11, 20)]

sorted_array = sorted(array,key=lambda x:(x[0].rjust(15),x[1:]))

print(sorted_array)
[('$', 0, 0), ('3', 3, 3), ('5', 7, 11), ('7', 5, 6), ('15', 6, 9), 
 ('16', 11, 20), ('17', 8, 13), ('18', 9, 16), ('19', 10, 18)]
```

Comment: This is a nice hack (+1), but you need to estimate the upper bound of the numbers you'll evaluate. Also generating the strings adds a extra cost. ;)