# Comparing Colors with comparison operators (> and <) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anyone explain how does Python perceives colors?
I saw the following line of code in the course:

> print("Yellow">"Cyan" and "Brown">"Magenta")

With the output ‘**False**’

If we would change the code to:

> print("Yellow">"Cyan" and "Brown"<"Magenta")

Then the output would be ‘**True**’

How does Python assumes what’s > and what’s < ?

///

[Screenshot of console from the course](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEg3U.png)

It’s part of the Google IT Automation with Python Professional Certificate

Crash Course on Python

Comment: `"Cyan"` is not a colour, it's a string ... think alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Whats happening**
When comparing Strings with ">" or "<", the individual characters are compared to each other.
If one character comes before the other in lexicographical order, it is smaller.
If both characters are the same, the next character of the string is compared.
e.g.:

```
"Yellow" > "Cyan" == true
```

because "Y" comes after "C" in the alphabet.

The same goes for

```
"Brown" > "Magenta" == false
```

because "B" comes before "M" and is therefore smaller.

**Why it works like this**
When comparing characters, the [ascii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) values of the characters are compared.
Hence "B" (which is interpreted as '66') is smaller then "M" ('77').

You can check this yourself with:

```
print(chr(66)) # Will output 'B'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are comparing strings without any attached meaning from the perspective of the Python interpreter. [This thread nicely demonstrates how strings are compared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/how-are-strings-compared).