# Why is my code not displaying the correct max when I type in "bob" in between other numbers?

Tags: python

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    try:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == "done":
            break
        print(num)

        if smallest is None :
            smallest = num
        elif num < smallest :
            smallest = num
        print(smallest, num)

        if largest is None:
            largest = num
        elif num > largest:
            largest = num
            print(largest, num)

    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue

print('Max', largest)
print("Minimum", smallest)
```

Asked to find the largest and smallest number from the input but if you type in a non number it mistakes that as the max value instead of calling it a "invalid input". Help?

Comment: can you fix you post a bit, I kinda get your question but cant read your code cause of the formatting

Comment: What you get as `num` are actually strings, because `input` returns strings. Then Python does string comparison instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/how-are-strings-compared

Comment: It's because you're working with strings, not numbers. You should transform the input to string: `num = int(input("Enter a number: "))`.

Comment: "input" always returns a string which you first have to convert to a number (with "int" or "float") to make it work correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: Try to use "9" and "19" as inputs and see what happens :)

Comment: I also see you want to check if the user input "done" so you could check for that, and afterword "num=int(num)" so your now owrking with an integer if they didnt input "done"

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the fact that the value of "num" is being treated like a string.  If you want to trigger an error exception refer to a revised version of your code with the attempted population of a numeric variable.

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    try:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == "done":
            break
        print(num)
        
        x = int(num)    # Add this in to force an error exception

        if smallest is None :
            smallest = num
        elif num < smallest :
            smallest = num
        print("Smallest:", smallest, num)

        if largest is None:
            largest = num
        elif num > largest:
            largest = num
            print("Largest:", largest, num)

    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue

print('Max', largest)
print("Minimum", smallest)
```

That should provide the error condition you are after.

Comment: Thank you I would have never thought of this would have been stuck for years.

Comment: This is incorrect, as it is still comparing the numbers as strings. If I give it the numbers 2 and 100, it says "max 2, minimum 100".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to compare strings, instead of integers. When you compare strings, Python uses lexical order to compare them.

```
print("100" < "2") # Prints "True", because "1" is lower than "2" in lexical order
```

If you compare integers instead, then Python will use numerical order, which is what you expect here.

```
print(100 < 2) # Prints "False", because 100 is greater than 2
```

To fix this, you can convert your input to a integer before comparing it. This should be done after checking whether the input equals "done", because "done" cannot be converted to an integer.

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    try:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == "done":
            break
        print(num)

        num = int(num)
        if smallest is None :
            smallest = num
        elif num < smallest :
            smallest = num
        print(smallest, num)

        if largest is None:
            largest = num
        elif num > largest:
            largest = num
            print(largest, num)

    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue

print('Max', largest)
print("Minimum", smallest)
```

Also, if you want to allow fractional numbers like `1.2`, then you can use `float` instead of `int`.

```
num = float(num)
```

Comment: Thanks will keep this in mind for all future code.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the type of exception you're looking for, and limit the window the exception can occur in as much as possible, this helps with trying to debug situations like this:

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while (num := input("Enter a number: ")) != 'done':
    try:
        num = float(num)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Input")
        continue
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = num
    elif num < smallest:
        smallest = num
    if largest is None:
        largest = num
    elif num > largest:
        largest = num

print('Max:', largest)
print("Minimum:", smallest)
```