# If statement is going wrong

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I've got a challenge to write a code to find the maximum in a list of numbers with no usage of such functions as max(), but only using for and if statement.

Hello, guys!
So, here is my code:

```
student_scores = input ("Input a list of scores the students have got till now:\n").split(", ")
print ("Okkay, here is your list of student scores: ", student_scores)

max_ = student_scores[0]
for score in student_scores:
    if score > max_:
        max_ = score
print (max_)
```

but if I type such a list:

```
11, 44, 8, 234
```

the result is:
**8**

If I add

```
int()
```

function to **score** and **max_** variables, everything is correct.
What's going wrong in that case? Help!

Comment: [How are strings compared?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4806911)

Comment: "8" is indeed higher, in alphabetical order, than any of "11", "44", or "234".  You aren't dealing with numbers here, these are all strings.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the string comparison.

```
student_scores = input ("Input a list of scores the students have got till now:\n").split(", ")
```

This line returns list of strings.

```
['11', '44', '8', '234']
```

Here is an answer about string comparison.
[How are strings compared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/how-are-strings-compared)

and there is more better way to do this

```
student_scores = input("Input a list of scores the students have got till now:\n").split(",")

max_score = max((int(score)for score in student_scores))
```

Comment: yeah, used 'type()' function to check it, right. 'input()' always returns string. just forgot about this...
Got it, thank you a lot!