# Sorting a List of Strings, Ignoring ASCII Ordinal Values

Tags: python, sorting, ordinal

I want to sort this list:

```
>>> L = ['A', 'B', 'C', ... 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', ... 'AZ', 'BA' ...]
```

Exactly the way it is, regardless of the contents (assuming all CAPS alpha).

```
>>> L.sort()
>>> L
['A', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC'...]
```

How can I make this:

```
>>> L.parkinglot_sort()
>>> L
['A', 'B', 'C', ... ]
```

I was thinking of testing for length, and sorting each length, and mashing all the separate 1-length, 2-length, n-length elements of `L` into the new `L`.

Thanks!

Comment: Ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659524/how-to-sort-by-length-of-string-followed-by-alphabetical-order


I think it is that you want :)
J.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this?

```
l.sort(key=lambda element: (len(element), element))
```

It will sort the list taking into account not only each element, but also its length.

```
>>> l = ['A', 'AA', 'B', 'BB', 'C', 'CC']
>>> l.sort(key=lambda element: (len(element), element))
>>> print l
['A', 'B', 'C', 'AA', 'BB', 'CC']
```

Comment: Oh hey...an anonymous function to do the measurement before sorting...<woooosh!> *lambda statement flying over head*