# python object list, sort in descending order based on object attribute

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of objects, which I need to sort by one of the objects attributes.

I can sort in ascending order with the following code

```
list1 = sorted(list1, key=lambda object1: object1.fitness)
```

However, this sorts the list by ascending order and what I need to do is sort by descending. Is this possible when sorting a list of objects?

Comment: operator.attrgetter instead of a lambda might also be useful

Comment: @SethMMorton thanks! included into the answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Specify `reverse=True` argument:

```
list1 = sorted(list1, key=lambda object1: object1.fitness, reverse=True)
```

Demo (simple list of integers):

```
>>> l = [6, 0, 2, 3, 1, 5, 4]
>>> sorted(l)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> sorted(l, reverse=True)
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Demo (datetime.dates, using `operator.attrgetter` instead of `lambda` as @SethMMorton suggested):

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> from operator import attrgetter
>>> l = [date(2014, 4, 11), date(2014, 4, 2), date(2014, 4, 3), date(2014, 4, 8)]

>>> sorted(l, key=attrgetter('day'))
[datetime.date(2014, 4, 2), 
 datetime.date(2014, 4, 3), 
 datetime.date(2014, 4, 8), 
 datetime.date(2014, 4, 11)]
>>> sorted(l, key=attrgetter('day'), reverse=True)
[datetime.date(2014, 4, 11), 
 datetime.date(2014, 4, 8), 
 datetime.date(2014, 4, 3), 
 datetime.date(2014, 4, 2)]
```

Comment: another alternative is using cmp_to_key helper function and creating your own object comparator

Comment: Perfect, cheers! just got to wait 6 mins before I can accept the answer haha

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362744/how-does-pythons-cmp-to-key-function-work) to craete your own comparator. You can even compare by multiple attributes or complex logic.

It works as this: cmp_to_key expects a function giving `key = cmp_to_key(obj)` where `obj` is an object to be sorted. Finally an object implementing comparator operators is returned, and can be used so you can do any custom comparisson logic.