# ruby sort array by length then alphabetically

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I'm trying to turn a string into an array sorted first by descending length, then by descending alphabetical order among strings of similar length. That is, "x ya yz z" should return ["yz", "ya", "z", "x"]. I see that an analogous question was posed in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659524/how-to-sort-by-length-of-string-followed-by-alphabetical-order). What would the ruby way be?

I understand the string can be sorted by descending length with

```
string = 'Joe John Bill Juan Bill'

x = string.split.sort_by(&:length).reverse.uniq
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
string.split.sort_by { |e| -e.length }.group_by(&:length).map{ |_, v| v.sort.reverse }.flatten
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`Array#sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-sort) with the size and the string itself like this:

```
array = 'Joe John Bill Juan Bill'
array.split(' ').sort { |a, b| [b.size, b] <=> [a.size, a] }
#=> ["Juan", "John", "Bill", "Bill", "Joe"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"x ya yz z".split.sort_by{|s| [s.length, s]}.reverse
# => ["yz", "ya", "z", "x"]
```