# text pattern recognition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pattern-matching

I am trying to get python to match a text pattern in pandas dataframe.

What i am doing is

```
list = ['sarcasm','irony','humor']
pattern = '|'.join(list)
pattern2 = str("( " + pattern.strip().lstrip().rstrip() + " )").strip().lstrip().rstrip()

frame = pd.DataFrame(docs_list, columns=['words'])
# docs_list is the list containing the snippets

#Skipping the inbetween steps for the simplicity of viewing
cp2 = frame.words.str.extract(pattern2)
c2 = cp2.to_frame().fillna("No Matching Word Found")
```

Which gives an output like this

```
Snips                                     pattern_found    matching_Word
A different type of humor                    True             humor
A different type of sarcasm                  True             sarcasm 
A different type of humor and irony          True             humor
A different type of reason                   False            NA
A type of humor and sarcasm                  True             humor
A type of comedy                             False            NA
```

So, python checks for the pattern and gives the corresponding output.

Now, here is my problem.
As per my understanding, as long as python does not encounter a word from the pattern in the snippet, it keeps on checking for the entire pattern. As soon as it encounters a part of the pattern, it takes that part and skips the remaining words.

How do i make python to look for every word rather than just the first matching word, in order that it outputs like thus?

```
Snips                                     pattern_found    matching_Word
A different type of humor                    True             humor
A different type of sarcasm                  True             sarcasm 
A different type of humor and irony          True             humor
A different type of humor and irony          True             irony
A different type of reason                   False            NA
A type of humor and sarcasm                  True             humor
A type of humor and sarcasm                  True             sarcasm
A type of comedy                             False            NA
```

A simple solution would obviously be to put the pattern in a list and iterate over a for loop by checking for every word in every snippet. But time is a constraint. especially because the data set i am dealing with is huge and the snips are fairly long.

Comment: Did you check [`extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html#pandas.Series.str.extractall)?

Comment: BTW, do you know the space in your `pattern2` is meaningful? You need to remove the spaces from `"( "` and `" )"`. The way you define a regex, you might as well use `pattern = r'({})'.format('|'.join(list))`. However, since the alternation is not anchored, you need to sort the items by length descending.

Comment: No, i had not tried extractall before. But now i did, combined with the other answer provided, and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me works [`extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for remove level of `MultiIndex`, last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original.

```
L = ['sarcasm','irony','humo', 'humor', 'hum']
#sorting by http://stackoverflow.com/a/4659539/2901002
L.sort()
L.sort(key = len, reverse=True)
print (L)
['sarcasm', 'humor', 'irony', 'humo', 'hum']

pattern2 = r'(?P<COL>{})'.format('|'.join(L))
print (pattern2)
(?P<COL>sarcasm|irony|humor|humo|hum)

cp2 = frame.words.str.extractall(pattern2).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
print (cp2)
       COL
0    humor
1  sarcasm
2    humor
2    irony
4    humor
4  sarcasm

frame = frame.join(cp2['COL']).reset_index(drop=True)
print (frame)
                                 words pattern_found matching_Word      COL
0            A different type of humor          True         humor    humor
1          A different type of sarcasm          True       sarcasm  sarcasm
2  A different type of humor and irony          True         humor    humor
3  A different type of humor and irony          True         humor    irony
4           A different type of reason         False           NaN      NaN
5          A type of humor and sarcasm          True         humor    humor
6          A type of humor and sarcasm          True         humor  sarcasm
7                     A type of comedy         False           NaN      NaN
```

Comment: And if your input contains `L = ['sarcasm','irony','humo', 'humor', 'hum']`? It won't work any longer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - You are right, unfortunately. I am not regex expert, so now I have NO solution for it.

Comment: Well, I already shared what needs to be done in my second comment to the question. Just sort the `L` list by length in descending order, then join with `|`.