# Length-wise-sorted list but, same length in alphabetical-order in a step

Tags: python, python-2.6

My Python List of string is something like `x` but long enough:

```
x = ['aaa','ab','aa','c','a','b','ba']
```

I wants to sort this list as:  `['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'aaa']` and I did as follows in **two** steps:

```
>>> x.sort()   
>>> x.sort(key=len)      
>>> x
['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'aaa']
```

But I need in one-step: I also tied using `lambda` function ([**taken help**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655591/python-sort-list)):

```
>>> x.sort(key=lambda item: (item, len(item)))
>>> x
['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'ab', 'b', 'ba', 'c']
```

But not as I desired:

Is it possible in one-step? Please me.

My Python:

```
~$ python --version  
Python 2.6.6
```

Comment: I edited the `python-2.7` tag to `python-2.6` as you clearly state you are using 2.6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You got the order of the tuple the wrong way round. When Python sorts on tuples, the first value is the *main* sort, with the second being the subsort, etc... - your code presumes the opposite order.

You want to sort by length, *then* alphabetically:

```
>>> x.sort(key=lambda item: (len(item), item))
>>> x
['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'aaa']
```

Edit: As DSM points out in the comments, Python sorts letters as capitals first, then lowercase. If this behaviour isn't wanted, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36156/722121).

Comment: This actually doesn't sort alphabetically due to case issues (but that's easily fixed.)  [I admit the OP's list is all lowercase at the moment.]

Comment: @DSM I was emulating the behaviour of the original - supposedly - working code, it could be a bug that capitals will come first, but that could be the desired behaviour, it's unclear.

Comment: @Lattyware : My work done, And I understood. But A last doubt. How first 2-step solution works? I sorted by alphabetic then length!.Thats the reason i could not think of what you tried..

Comment: Your first solution works because when Python sorts on a key, and values are equal, it does a stable sort - that is, the order of equal values is the order they were in the input. This means that if you sort by one value, then by another, the first sort *falls through* as a subsort.

Comment: @Lattyware I read so many time in python book this term `stable sort` but I understood the meaning today.. Thanks Now completely got it.

Answer (score 1):

using `itertools.grouby()`:

```
In [29]: lis = ['aaa','ab','aa','c','a','b','ba']
In [30]: list(chain(*[sorted(g) for k,g in groupby(sorted(lis,key=len),key=len)]))
Out[30]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'aaa']
```

`timeit` comparisons:

```
In [38]: x = ['aaa','ab','aa','c','a','b','ba']*1000

In [39]: random.shuffle(x)

#may be in more tricky test cases this would be fast

In [40]: %timeit sorted(x,key=lambda item: (len(item), item))
100 loops, best of 3: 11.3 ms per loop

In [41]: %timeit list(chain(*[sorted(g) for k,g in groupby(sorted(x,key=len),key=len)]))
100 loops, best of 3: 7.82 ms per loop
```

Comment: This seems massively overcomplicated. Not wrong, but... I don't really see the value of it.

Comment: I like `itertools` as much as the next guy, but this is whoa-crazy-crazy!  PS: you don't need the `list` call, `sorted` will consume `g` and produce a list.

Comment: @DSM Forgot to remove the `list()` call, was using it for testing purpose. I know it's a weird way compared to lattyware's answer, but peformance wise this was faster.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary nice simulation..this aptitude is very good and required..thanks again!