# Python sorting : sub strings

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7

In Python

```
s= "ABCC"
n = len(s)
sorted(set([s[a:b] for a in range(n) for b in range(a+1,n+2)])
```

gives me, alphabetically sorted sub strings with out repetitions

```
['A', 'AB', 'ABC', 'ABCC', 'B', 'BC', 'BCC', 'C', 'CC']
```

How can I further sort it by length of sub string.

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'AB', 'BC', 'CC', 'ABC', 'BCC', 'ABCC']
```

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103620/length-wise-sorted-list-but-same-length-in-alphabetical-order-in-a-step

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple,

```
sorted(set(s[a:b] for a in range(n) for b in range(a+1,n+1)),
       key=lambda x:(len(x),x))
```

This creates a key by which the comparison is done.  First it compares the string lengths to determine the order.  If the strings have the same length, the tie-breaker is the string contents.

Answer (score 2):

This is your solution:

```
s= "ABCC"
n = len(s)
sorted(sorted(set([s[a:b] for a in range(n) for b in range(a+1,n+2)])),key=len)
```

Comment: And how is that solution wrong? Did you run it yourself? Please run it in Python and tell me if it is wrong or not.

Comment: Python sorting is guaranteed to be stable, so there's nothing wrong about double `sorted`. Upvoted.

Comment: I missed the fact that you're using two `sorted` calls(ignore my last comment(deleted)), +1.

Comment: mgilson....Could you prove your point? I have tested this with this string also
s= "NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM"

Comment: I am wondering why two times sorting is required, 'set' sorts the list alphabetically, then you sort the with sorted for len.

Comment: @AUZKamath set does not do any sorting. It only constructs an unordered collection. Then the first sorted sorts alphabetically and the second one sorts that alphabetically sorted collection by length.